# Как сделать, что бы в IDLE импортировался по умолчанию модуль pprint?

Tags: python, idle

Как сделать, что бы в IDLE (только в shell)  импортировался по умолчанию модуль pprint (что-бы не импортировать каждый раз вручную)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеется системная переменная [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP), в которую можно записать путь и имя скрипта, который должен быть выполнен интерпретатором перед запуском программы. Создайте файл с директивами импорта и укажите его в `PYTHONSTARTUP`.